# Is the CPD3213 error linked to AS400 version?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to use CHGPF with MAXMBRS(*NOMAX) for a PF created from SQL table. Earlier in AS400 version V5r3M0, it used to work fine. Now the server has been upgraded to V7R1M0. Now the program is failing. Is it related to AS400 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SQL table on DB2 for i can only have a single member unless you have DB2 Multisystem installed. This (separately charged) licensed program enables a thing called a partitioned table which is implemented using multi-member physical files. There is a good chance that this was locked down somewhere between v5r3 and v6r1. If you are just switching from v5r3 to v7.1, there is a good chance your company is trying to save money by using old unsupported hardware and software. (v7.1 is past its support lifetime) In this case, you probably won't have access to DB2 Multisystem as it is very expensive.

One alternative is to use DDS defined physical files. These can have multiple members, and you can access these members (one at a time) using overrides or SQL aliases. There are some things though, such as identity columns, that you can't define using DDS.

Comment: How to check if the DB2 Multisystem is installed in the System?

Comment: you might try `GO LICPGM` and look for 5770-SS1 option 27 in the list of installed licensed programs. 5770-SS1 is the OS, option 27 is DB2 Multisystem. Like I said, it is licensed separately from the OS, so even though you will see 5770-SS1, there is a good chance that option 27 will be missing.